# How to stop text flowing under floated image

Tags: css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GevgKR?editors=1100

I have a grid style layout that turns into a card layout on smaller screens

The grid layout is created with flex. In the card layout all the elements are floated left. The layout has an image at the start, and so the text warps underneath the image.

How can I stop the text wrapping underneath the image.

I think I need to create a type of fake column on the left for image. I can do this with flex but this would effect the layout on the desktop view as thats done with flex

```
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 1366px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


.grid{
  &__row{
    display: flex;
  }

  &__cell{
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    flex: 1;
  }
}


@media(max-width: 700px){


  .grid{
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 8px;
    &__row{
      display: block;
      &-header{
        display: none;
      }
    }

    &__cell{
      border: none;
      float: left;

      &-image{
        height: auto;
        clear: right;
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: seems to be working fine in the codepen... can you post an image showing what is going on and what you pretend?

Comment: I have updated the codepen in the question with more columns, on smaller screen sizes now you can see that the text wraps underneath the image

Comment: You can have a `container` which will wrap your `grids` which you have created.
Basically the image and this container will be siblings.

Here is an example : https://codepen.io/Utsav91/pen/NJvPOw?editors=1100

You would have to play around the `flex` for both the image and container.